# Adjacent Bit Counts

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

here is the [problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/GNYR09F/) from spoj that states

> For a string of n bits x1,x2,x3,...,Xn
>   the adjacent bit count of the string
>   (AdjBC(x)) is given by
>
> X1*X2 + X2*X3 + X3*X4 + ... + Xn-1 *
>   Xn
>
> which counts the number of times a 1
>   bit is adjacent to another 1 bit. For
>   example:
>
> AdjBC(011101101) = 3 
>   AdjBC(111101101) = 4 
>   AdjBC(010101010) = 0

and the question is  : Write a program which takes as input integers n and k and returns the number of bit strings x of n bits (out of 2ⁿ) that satisfy AdjBC(x) = k.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can you help me to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Try anding the number with itself shifted one bit to the right, then count the resulting 1's in the outcome. ie. `X & (X >> 1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Often in combinatorial problems, it helps to look at the set of values it produces. Using brute force I calculated the following table:

```
  k   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
n +----------------------------
1 |   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 |   3   1   0   0   0   0   0
3 |   5   2   1   0   0   0   0
4 |   8   5   2   1   0   0   0
5 |  13  10   6   2   1   0   0
6 |  21  20  13   7   2   1   0
7 |  34  38  29  16   8   2   1
```

The first column is the familiar Fibonacci sequence, and satisfies the recurrence relation `f(n, 0) = f(n-1, 0) + f(n-2, 0)`

The other columns satisfies the recurrence relation `f(n, k) = f(n - 1, k) + f(n - 1, k - 1) + f(n - 2, k) - f(n - 2, k - 1)`

With this, you can do some dynamic programming:

```
INPUT: n, k
row1 <- [2,0,0,0,...] (k+1 elements)
row2 <- [3,1,0,0,...] (k+1 elements)
repeat (n-2) times
  for j = k downto 1 do
    row1[j] <- row2[j] + row2[j-1] + row1[j] - row1[j-1]
  row1[0] <- row1[0] + row2[0]
  swap row1 and row2
return row2[k]
```

Comment: Is there any proof also for f(n,0) by combinatorics other than by actually building the table with brute force?

Comment: For 0 adjacent `1`'s, you start with a `0` or `1`. If it is `0`, the next bit can be either value. If it is `1`, the next bit can only be `0`. In other words, you can wither add `10` or `0`.
A sequence of length `n` can be formed by taking a sequence of length `n-2` and adding `10`, or taking a sequence of length `n-1` and adding `0`. This is the same relation as the familiar Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 7):

As a hint you can split it up into two cases: numbers ending in 0 and numbers ending in 1.

```
def f(n, k):
    return f_ending_in_0(n, k) + f_ending_in_1(n, k)

def f_ending_in_0(n, k):
    if n == 1: return k == 0
    return f(n - 1, k)

def f_ending_in_1(n, k):
    if n == 1: return k == 0
    return f_ending_in_0(n - 1, k) + f_ending_in_1(n - 1, k - 1)
```

This gives the correct output but takes a long time to execute. You can apply standard dynamic programming or memoization techniques to get this to perform fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

I am late to the party, but I have a linear time complexity solution.

For me this is more of a mathematical problem. You can read the detailed solution in this [blog post](https://math.mrpandey.com/post/2018/adjacent-bit-counts/) written by me. What follows is a brief outline. I wish I could put some LaTeX, but SO doesn't allows that.

Suppose for given `n` and `k`, our answer is given by the function `f(n,k)`. Using Beggar's Method, we can arrive at the following formula

`f(n,k) = SUM C(k+a-1,a-1)*C(n-k+1-a,a)`, where `a` runs from `1` to `(n-k+1)/2`

Here `C(p,q)` denotes binomial coefficients.

So to get our answer, we have to calculate both the binomial coefficients for each value of `a`. We can calculate the binomial table beforehand. This approach will then given our answer in `O(n^2)` since we have to calculate the table.

We can improve the time complexity by using the recursion formula `C(p,q) = (p * C(p-1,q-1))/q` to calculate the current value of binomial coefficients from their values in previous loop.

Our final code looks like this:

```
long long x=n-k, y=1, p=n-k+1, ans=0;
ans += x*y;

for(int a=2; a<=p/2; a++)
{
    x = (x*(p-2*a+1)*(p-2*a+2))/(a*(p-a+1));
    y = (y*(k+a-1))/(a-1);
    ans += x*y;
}
```

You can find the complete accepted solution in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mrpandey/spoj/blob/master/solved/GNYR09F.cpp).